# Having trouble building Z3 in Visual Studio

Tags: z3

Hello I downloaded Z3 from http://z3.codeplex.com/ and then opened the Z3 solution in Visual Studio 2012. (While I'm not totally new to VS I haven't used it in over 10 years). There are 9 projects in this solution but I am having a hard time telling which I ought to be using. I can guess at some of them, but others aren't very clear. Eg. what is the difference between Microsoft.Z3 and Microsoft.Z3V3 ? Can anyone briefly explain what the different projects are and which ones to build?

Anyway just for kicks I tried building the top level solution but got the following errors

Error   1   error RC1015: cannot open include file 'afxres.h'.  C:\Projects\z3-src-4.1.2\z3\dll\dll.rc  10  1   dll

Error 2 (same as Error 1 except in shell.rc)

Error   3   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Projects\z3-src-4.1.2\z3\Debug\z3_dbg.lib'  C:\Projects\z3-src-4.1.2\z3\test_capi\LINK  test_capi

Trying to build just the MS.Z3 project still gives me Error 1.

My eventual goal is to invoke Z3 from say an F# program. Can someone provide some guidance for how to do this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

*This answer reflects the [directory structure](http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/ae1595360992aa67b6ba55118a6e0e729b786db4#README) used in Z3 version <= 4.1.1. In version 4.3, the code base has been reorganized/simplified.*

**END EDIT**

Which version of Visual Studio are you using? I'm asking because I want to reproduce the behavior you described.
The easiest way to build Z3 is described [here](http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1cfe6e477a3d#README). 
You should use the Visual Studio Command Prompt, and execute `msbuild`. It seems you tried that, and got errors. Here is a short description of each project folder:

- `lib`: the Z3 source code is here. This is the important folder. For visual studio users, it generated a static library.
- `dll`: project for wrapping the static library as a Windows DLL. This is irrelevant for users in other platforms.
- `shell`: uses the static library from `lib` to build `z3.exe`.
- `test`: a bunch of unit tests. It produces `test.exe`.
- `Microsoft.Z3`: .Net API. It is the official .Net API (C#, Visual Basic, F#, etc) for Z3. This is the API you should use with F#.
- `Microsoft.Z3V3`: It is the old .NET API. It was the API available in Z3 3.x. We maintain it because some users still use it.
- `test_capi`: Application that tests the Z3 C API.
- `maxsat`: Small application that implements two maxsat algorithms on top of the Z3 API.

Comment: thanks! I am using VS Professional 2012 Ver. 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL. I did previously look at the README but I don't have an "msbuild" command in my VS installation, only a folder called msbuild which contains some XML definitions. Are the instructions given perhaps for VS 2010?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see you meant VS command line and not a regular command line. I am trying the command line build now.

Comment: OK, it finished. It reported the 2 errors regarding afxres.h as the Studio build did but not the link error of the studio. Perhaps it just didnt get as far? Here's the transcript of the output below:

Comment: It reported the 2 errors regarding afxres.h as the Studio build did but not the link error of the studio.  `"C:\Projects\z3-src-4.1.2\z3\z3-prover.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Projects\z3-src-4.1.2\z3\shell\shell.vcxproj" (default target) (3) ->
(ResourceCompile target) ->
  shell.rc(10): fatal error RC1015: cannot open include file 'afxres.h'. 

"C:\Projects\z3-src-4.1.2\z3\z3-prover.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Projects\z3-src-4.1.2\z3\dll\dll.vcxproj" (default target) (4) ->  dll.rc(10): fatal error RC1015: cannot open include file 'afxres.h'.`

Comment: I will install VS 2012 and try again. I'm currently using VS 2010.

Comment: hi, I was wondering if there was any news on this or should i revert back to VS 2010? Also, I'm wondering if the Windows binaries could be made available again. The Z3 page says that they are but i couldn't find them for the recent release of Z3

Comment: We will provide windows binaries at codeplex. We are just trying to figure out how to automate the process. Here is a list of all released Windows binaries: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/older_z3.html

Comment: Just thought I'd enquire one last time if Z3 i working yet in VS 2012 before i go and dig out 2010. Thanks!

Comment: We have pre-compiled binaries at codeplex http://z3.codeplex.com/releases. We also have a new build system for Z3. It works on VS 2010 and 2012. You can find compilation instructions here: http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/89c1785b7322#README

Comment: ok thanks. I didn't find the python scripts included in the download so i pasted the contents myself individually. Anyway, when i tried building I get :
C:\ProgramFiles\Z3-4.3>python scripts\mk_make.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts\mk_make.py", line 9, in <module>
    from mk_util import *
  File "C:\ProgramFiles\Z3-4.3\scripts\mk_util.py", line 81
    print "dos2unix '%s'" % fname
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

C:\ProgramFiles\Z3-4.3>

Comment: btw i am running python 3.3.0

Comment: The scripts are all based on python 2.7.x. Z3Py is also for python 2.7.x.

Comment: ok i tried with 2.7.x. This time I get:

C:\ProgramFiles\Z3-4.3>python scripts\mk_make.py
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts\mk_make.py", line 14, in <module>
    API_files = init_project_def()
  File "C:\ProgramFiles\Z3-4.3\scripts\mk_project.py", line 72, in init_project_
def
    set_z3py_dir('api/python')
  File "C:\ProgramFiles\Z3-4.3\scripts\mk_util.py", line 211, in set_z3py_dir
    raise MKException("Python bindings directory '%s' does not exist" % full)
mk_exception.MKException: "Python bindings directory 'src/api/python' does not e
xist"

C:\ProgramFiles\Z3-4.3>

Comment: Have you tried the instructions at: http://z3.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Z3Py%20on%20Windows

Comment: Ah I was not aware of these additional instructions. I will try them and let you know. Thanks